# Transit visa in India for a French Citizen?

Tags: visas, india, transit, french-citizens, del

As a French person, I booked a ticket from CountryA to [Delhi](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Delhi), and another ticket (other company/agent) from Delhi to CountryB.

CountryA → Delhi  → CountryB → Delhi → CountryA

Do I need a [visa](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/India#Visas) to change companies at Delhi?
I will need to pick up my luggages at Delhi and drop them at the CompanyB counter.

I have applied for a multiple entry visa, and got it (see below) but unfortunately this part makes me think I won't be able to use it when coming back: `Not valid for 2nd entry within two months of last exit from India`. Only 2 weeks will have past when I come back to India with the return flights.

[image]

**QUESTION:**  Is there something like a transit visa that I could use the second time?

Comment: So I went and when trying to enter a second time, the officer was not willing to let me in, I explained how I just needed to take my luggage and check back in. He called two others colleagues and they finally let me in after discussing with each other for a while.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same situation, flying to Delhi, and visiting Nepal before returning to Delhi. The embassy can issue a special waiver of the "no returns within two months" rule.

Personally I was on a multiple entry business visa, but I forgot to get the special waiver. Nobody said anything when I returned after a weekend in Nepal, but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE** It seems that the requirement of a minimum stay outside of India for 2 months has been lifted on 4th Dec 2012: http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/news.html

> This is for information that restriction of TWO months gap between two
>   visits has been removed by the Government of India from 4th Dec 2012.
>   This stipulation of two months gap does not apply on any other type of
>   visa, i.e. Business (B) or Entry (X) types of visas. It also does not
>   apply to PIO and OCI card holders.

However, it seems that one still needs to get a permission to reenter within the two months:

> In case of requirement to visit India within 2 months, permission
>   should be sought, where applicable, from the High Commission of
>   India(...)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** This was valid before 4th Dec 2012

As far as I know you need a double-entry visa, which is specifically designed for this kind of travel - when you go to India, then from there go to a neighbouring country (warning: the list of countries is rather limited) and then come back to India. In this case you have to limits on the time spent in the other country.

Comment: You linked to the standard tourist visa. You're correct that a double/any entry visa is needed, but it's NOT the standard tourist visa - the link needs to be for the transit visa.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee, thanks for letting me know. The web site has changed, because they actually removed this 2-month limitation! I will update my answer.

Comment: I assume the new rule is for visa issued after Dec 4th, he already has a visa that says otherwise.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf, difficult to tell.

Answer (score 5):

Visa requirements depend on your nationality.

For some citizens, [a tourist visa can be obtained upon arrival](http://www.immigrationindia.nic.in/visa_on_arrival2.htm). But I wouldn't rely solely on the information in the previous link. Read, for example, [this](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2012-01-22/india/30652225_1_visa-regime-skill-development-voa).

Meanwhile, many (all?) of India's consulates now have outsourced visa application procedures to third parties, meaning that there doesn't seem to be much consistency between consulates. See for example the [UK](http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/) and [US](https://indiavisa.travisaoutsourcing.com/consular-fees?id=4) processes.

So, if I were you, I'd ask for details at your nearest consulate and tell them your situation.

(I know, not really an answer to your question, but, specifically without knowing your nationality, it's a difficult, if not impossible one, to answer. And even then, with India's fairly opaque visa laws, regularly in flux, I would still suggest confirming with a consulate.)

Comment: So sorry I totally forgot to add this essential information! Fixed now.

Comment: Cool. I don't think (but am not sure) that the French have it easier getting a visa for India than others. Hence I suppose why you got a visa before going in the first place :) But, I suppose, you should still check with a consulate.

Answer (score 5):

There is a long thread over on [Thorn Tree](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1950292&start=15) about the same question.

While there are lots of different opinions, it seems that **if both flights are from Terminal 3**, you don't need to go through immigration and **don't need a transit or other visa at all.**

Here's a quote from one of the posts:

> Please note, both your flights will arrive and depart from the new
> International Terminal –T3 and no transit Visa is required for
> passengers having onward International Connection. Passengers having
> onward International connection wait in the transfer area, in case
> they have through checked-in baggage .You will receive your onward
> boarding card in the transfer area. In case the baggage is not through
> tagged to the final destination, then you can contact the Transfer
> desk in the International Transfer area.
>
> For your information, the Airline personnel available at the transfer
> desk in the International transfer area will be able to assist you
> with your luggage. They will identify your baggage and tag it for the
> next destination. They will also give a part of the bag tag for your
> reference. With kind regards,
>
> Seema.
>
> Customer Response Management
>
> Delhi International Airport Pvt.
>
> Ltd. IGI Airport, New Delhi