# Transit visa for India or NOT?

Tags: visas, transit, india, uk-citizens

I will be travelling from Katmandu to Istanbul with a 5 hour stopover in Delhi is a transit visa required.I have British passport and will not be leaving international airport.

Comment: Does the [Transit visa in India?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/transit-visa-in-india?rq=1) question not cover you?

Comment: @Gagravarr to be fair, that's for a French citizen

Comment: [Although [this question totally has the answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/how-to-transit-through-delhi-without-a-visa) - transiting without a visa in Delhi - no?