# Do I need a transit visa for a 14 hour layover in India as a British Citizen?

Tags: visas, transit, india, uk-citizens

I have a flight in September from Thailand to the UK with a layover in India. The layover is just under 14 hours, I am a UK citizen and I do not plan on leaving the airport. I haven't been able to find any firm advice on whether I will need a transit visa. The UKGOV.com official site says a transit visa will be required to travel through India, as I am travelling by air into India and straight back out again, will I need a visa?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44467/transit-visa-for-india-or-not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transit visa in India?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/transit-visa-in-india)

Answer (score 2):

One possible duplicate has not (yet?) been answered and the other focuses on French citizenship and contains some information that seems inaccurate.

All the 'Indian' sites I have seen are of terrible quality and very confusing so I suggest relying on the unequivocal:

> To transit through India you will need a transit visa.

from [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/india/entry-requirements)

with support from [World Travel Guide](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/india/passport-visa):

> For UK nationals: transit visa: £56

and

> valid for three days of transit through India within 15 days of the date of issue.

At least at the moment you are not eligible for a visa-on-arrival arrangement.